# preg_replace for special formatting like "[m;9;34;1m"

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I cant find any PHP Regex clearing this string:

"[21m[0;34;1m[21m[HoaxPvP][m [21m[0;32;1mhi[m"
to:
"[HoaxPvP] hi"

thanks in advance if you find a regex for this.

Comment: Looks like VT100 or VT220 escape codes

Comment: *"I cant find any PHP Regex clearing this string"* ... Clear it of what? Which bits of it do you want to get rid of, and which bits do you want to keep? Do the codes have any meaning to you that you want to retain? What is your intended output? And have you tried anything already?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$subject = preg_replace('/\x1b(\[|\(|\))[;?0-9]*[0-9A-Za-z]/', "",$subject); 
$subject = preg_replace('/[\x03|\x1a]/', "", $subject);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
preg_replace('/\[[\d;]*m/', '', '[21m[0;34;1m[21m[HoaxPvP][m [21m[0;32;1mhi[m');
```